# Sort issue in shell script

Tags: shell

How to sort below example

**Input:**

```
n4Apple0.1banana
n1Apple0.4banana
n0Apple0.0banana
n2Apple0.3banana
```

**Output:**

```
n0Apple0.0banana
n4Apple0.1banana
n2Apple0.3banana
n1Apple0.4banana
```

Comment: Do you have some sample of code you have done? Or some commands you have used?

Comment: Look at the `sort` options `k`, `t` and `n`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
data="YourDataFile"
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
sed 's/\(.*\([01]\.[0-9]*\).*\)/\2\1/' "$data" | sort -n > "$tmpfile"
sed 's/^...//' "$tmpfile" > "$data"
rm "$tmpfile"
```

**explanation**

```
# get float from input an insert it at the front
sed 's/\(.*\([01]\.[0-9]*\).*\)/\2\1/' "$data"

0.1n4Apple0.1banana
0.4n1Apple0.4banana
0.0n0Apple0.0banana
0.3n2Apple0.3banana

# sort numeric and write into tmpfile
sort -n > "$tmpfile"

0.0n0Apple0.0banana
0.1n4Apple0.1banana
0.3n2Apple0.3banana
0.4n1Apple0.4banana

# extract float from the front an save it in your datafile
sed 's/^...//' "$tmpfile" > "$data"

n0Apple0.0banana
n4Apple0.1banana
n2Apple0.3banana
n1Apple0.4banana

# remove tmpfile
```

Comment: i dont want to take '.' as delimiter.

Comment: What happens if we have input like
n4Apple0.1banana
n1Apple0.4banana
n0Apple1.0banana
n2Apple0.3banana

expected result:
n4Apple0.1banana
n2Apple0.3banana
n1Apple0.4banana
n0Apple1.0banana

Comment: requirement is to sort based on float number(example 0.1,0.3,0.2 and 1.0 )